# Working example for signal protocol in js

Tags: javascript, encryption

Hi there i try to make i clientside message exchange with the signal protocol (only for tests). But i have trouble to the proccessPreKey.

Here is the test code

```
<script src="javascripts/libsignal-protocol.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/InMemorySignalProtocolStore.js"></script>
<script>
            var KeyHelperUser1 = libsignal.KeyHelper;
            var KeyHelperUser2 = libsignal.KeyHelper;

            var registrationId_User1 = KeyHelperUser1.generateRegistrationId();
            var registrationId_User2 = KeyHelperUser2.generateRegistrationId();
            // Store registrationId somewhere durable and safe.

            var identityKeyPair_User1, identityKeyPair_User2;
            var SignedPreKey_User1, SignedPreKey_User2;

            // Test Store
            var store_User1   = new SignalProtocolStore();
            var store_User2   = new SignalProtocolStore();

            var PreKey_User1, PreKey_User2;

            // Build the session
            var address_User1 = new libsignal.SignalProtocolAddress(1002, 0);
            var address_User2 = new libsignal.SignalProtocolAddress(1001, 0);

            var sessionBuilder_User1 = new libsignal.SessionBuilder(store_User1, address_User1);
            var sessionBuilder_User2 = new libsignal.SessionBuilder(store_User2, address_User2);

            KeyHelperUser1.generateIdentityKeyPair().then(function(identityKeyPair) {
                // keyPair -> { pubKey: ArrayBuffer, privKey: ArrayBuffer }
                // Store identityKeyPair somewhere durable and safe.
                identityKeyPair_User1 = identityKeyPair;

                KeyHelperUser1.generatePreKey(1001).then(function(preKey) {
                    //store.storePreKey(preKey.keyId, preKey.keyPair);
                    PreKey_User1 = preKey;
                    KeyHelperUser2.generatePreKey(1002).then(function(preKey) {
                        //store.storePreKey(preKey.keyId, preKey.keyPair);
                        PreKey_User2 = preKey;
                        KeyHelperUser1.generateSignedPreKey(identityKeyPair_User1, 1001).then(function(signedPreKey) {
                            store_User1.storeSignedPreKey(signedPreKey.keyId, signedPreKey.keyPair);
                            SignedPreKey_User1 = signedPreKey;


                            KeyHelperUser2.generateIdentityKeyPair().then(function(identityKeyPair) {
                                // keyPair -> { pubKey: ArrayBuffer, privKey: ArrayBuffer }
                                // Store identityKeyPair somewhere durable and safe.
                                identityKeyPair_User2 = identityKeyPair;

                                KeyHelperUser2.generateSignedPreKey(identityKeyPair_User2, 1002).then(function(signedPreKey) {
                                    store_User2.storeSignedPreKey(signedPreKey.keyId, signedPreKey.keyPair);
                                    SignedPreKey_User2 = signedPreKey;

                                    var promise_User1 = sessionBuilder_User1.processPreKey({
                                        registrationId: registrationId_User2,
                                        identityKey: identityKeyPair_User2.pubKey,
                                        signedPreKey: {
                                            keyId     : 1002,
                                            publicKey : SignedPreKey_User2.pubKey,
                                            signature : SignedPreKey_User2.signature
                                        },
                                        preKey: {
                                            keyId     : 1002,
                                            publicKey : PreKey_User1.pubKey
                                        }
                                    });

                                    promise_User1.catch(function onerror(error) {
                                        // handle identity key conflict
                                        //console.log(error);
                                    });

                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });


            });
        </script>
```

I don't really know which parameters the processPreKey wanted. Can someone help?

Comment: Hey, were you able to complete this? I am trying to basic setup for signal. Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 11):

Hey so this is something i put together, hope it helps.

```
var KeyHelper = libsignal.KeyHelper;

function generateIdentity(store) {
    return Promise.all([
        KeyHelper.generateIdentityKeyPair(),
        KeyHelper.generateRegistrationId(),
    ]).then(function(result) {
        store.put('identityKey', result[0]);
        store.put('registrationId', result[1]);
    });
}

function generatePreKeyBundle(store, preKeyId, signedPreKeyId) {
    return Promise.all([
        store.getIdentityKeyPair(),
        store.getLocalRegistrationId()
    ]).then(function(result) {
        var identity = result[0];
        var registrationId = result[1];

        return Promise.all([
            KeyHelper.generatePreKey(preKeyId),
            KeyHelper.generateSignedPreKey(identity, signedPreKeyId),
        ]).then(function(keys) {
            var preKey = keys[0]
            var signedPreKey = keys[1];

            store.storePreKey(preKeyId, preKey.keyPair);
            store.storeSignedPreKey(signedPreKeyId, signedPreKey.keyPair);

            return {
                identityKey: identity.pubKey,
                registrationId : registrationId,
                preKey:  {
                    keyId     : preKeyId,
                    publicKey : preKey.keyPair.pubKey
                },
                signedPreKey: {
                    keyId     : signedPreKeyId,
                    publicKey : signedPreKey.keyPair.pubKey,
                    signature : signedPreKey.signature
                }
            };
        });
    });
}

var ALICE_ADDRESS = new libsignal.SignalProtocolAddress("xxxxxxxxx", 1);
var BOB_ADDRESS   = new libsignal.SignalProtocolAddress("yyyyyyyyyyyyy", 1);

    var aliceStore = new libsignal.SignalProtocolStore();

    var bobStore = new libsignal.SignalProtocolStore();
    var bobPreKeyId = 1337;
    var bobSignedKeyId = 1;

    var Curve = libsignal.Curve;

        Promise.all([
            generateIdentity(aliceStore),
            generateIdentity(bobStore),
        ]).then(function() {
            return generatePreKeyBundle(bobStore, bobPreKeyId, bobSignedKeyId);
        }).then(function(preKeyBundle) {
            var builder = new libsignal.SessionBuilder(aliceStore, BOB_ADDRESS);
            return builder.processPreKey(preKeyBundle).then(function() {

              var originalMessage = util.toArrayBuffer("my message ......");
              var aliceSessionCipher = new libsignal.SessionCipher(aliceStore, BOB_ADDRESS);
              var bobSessionCipher = new libsignal.SessionCipher(bobStore, ALICE_ADDRESS);

              aliceSessionCipher.encrypt(originalMessage).then(function(ciphertext) {

                  // check for ciphertext.type to be 3 which includes the PREKEY_BUNDLE
                  return bobSessionCipher.decryptPreKeyWhisperMessage(ciphertext.body, 'binary');

              }).then(function(plaintext) {

                  alert(plaintext);

              });

              bobSessionCipher.encrypt(originalMessage).then(function(ciphertext) {

                  return aliceSessionCipher.decryptWhisperMessage(ciphertext.body, 'binary');

              }).then(function(plaintext) {

                  assertEqualArrayBuffers(plaintext, originalMessage);

              });

            });
        });
```

Comment: thank you! I spent a day reading unhelpful protobuf stack traces after following signal's readme. your code is simple and it works! you should submit a PR to replace their readme with a link to here ;)

Comment: I just tried your code but util.toArrayBuffer is not a function. Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: @SomeoneNew @dtudury I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) Error: No record for xxxxxxxxxxx.1` error. What do you think the error can be?

Comment: Would you mind sharing ideas for your store implementation? Is it just using local storage?

Comment: @JasonSaruulo 'store' is whatever you want it to be. LocalStorage would work, and so would IndexedDB.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment; just addressing the comments below the answer.

@Niczem Olaske, the util.toArrayBuffer([message]) can be removed. The returned ciphertext is already an arrayBuffer, and converting the message to an arrayBuffer prior to encryption creates the need to convert it back to a string at the end anyway. However, a global 'util' object must be declared in order for libsignal to work (at least in JavaScript). So you can just put: const util = {}; somewhere outside function bodies, or alternatively: Object.assign(window, { util: {} }); before using libsignal.

@Hasib Mahmud, this error is from Bob trying to encrypt a message to Alice when a session has not yet been established. If you use async/await instead of .then(() => etc...), you will avoid this problem. Bob must decrypt Alice's message first in order to establish a session with her, and then encrypt messages to her. **Note that he needs to use the 'decryptPreKeyWhisperMessage' method in order to use her preKey to establish the session whilst calling the method.** After the session has been established on both sides, he can use the 'decryptWhisperMessage' method.