# How can I setup Signal protocol

Tags: javascript, whisper

I am trying to setup Signal protocol. Can someone please help me with this. https://github.com/WhisperSystems/libsignal-protocol-javascript

They had given the below code to use at the install time (that is for setup). I am not able to complete this code. I want to store the key in the browser itself for now.

```
var KeyHelper = libsignal.KeyHelper;

var registrationId = KeyHelper.generateRegistrationId();
// Store registrationId somewhere durable and safe.

KeyHelper.generateIdentityKeyPair().then(function(identityKeyPair) {
    // keyPair -> { pubKey: ArrayBuffer, privKey: ArrayBuffer }
    // Store identityKeyPair somewhere durable and safe.
});

KeyHelper.generatePreKey(keyId).then(function(preKey) {
    store.storePreKey(preKey.keyId, preKey.keyPair);
});

KeyHelper.generateSignedPreKey(identityKeyPair, keyId).then(function(signedPreKey) {
    store.storeSignedPreKey(signedPreKey.keyId, signedPreKey.keyPair);
});

// Register preKeys and signedPreKey with the server
```

Comment: I have posted an intro code of how to use it here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456125/7995536

Comment: I too am surprised that Signal doesn't have a tutorial for an actual working example! It seems impossible to get started because they leave out lots of details. It's a shame because the idea sounds impressive and really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example
https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-java/pull/21/commits/3496ed996359f6d3d8ee52dcecb8f8b0d45b3cbc

This is Java based project but it might help you in your JS code
https://github.com/lvijay/DemoSignal